# For what values is given vector linear combination of two others?

Tags: linear-algebra

Here's the problem:

For what values of c is [1, c, c^2] a linear combination of [1, 2, 4] and [1, 3, 9]?

I know just by looking that c = 2 and c = 3 are solutions but I want to solve the problem systematically so I know there aren't other solutions.  Here's what I did:

a [1, 2, 4] + b [1, 3, 9] = [1, c, c^2]

So I end up with: [1, 1 | 1; 2, 3 | c; 4, 9 | c^2]

When I row reduce this, I get [1, 1 | 1; 0, 1 | c - 2; 0, 1 | (c^2 - 4) / 5]...not really sure where to go from here since:

b = c-2
a = 1 - b = 3 - c

Thoughts?

Thanks guys,
Mariogs

Answer (score 1):

You can stack all three vectors to a 3x3 matrix and compute the determinant. The vectors are linearly dependent if and only if the determinant is zero.

From the special structure of the matrix one can easily infer with Laplace expansion that the above condition is a 2 degree polynomial in $c$.

Since this has at most two solutions, this proves that two solutions you found by looking are the only ones.

(Of course the systemaic way is calculating the determinant and solving for $c$. But this is tediuous and "guessing" can save a lot of work and be rigorous at the same time).

Comment: Hey @AndreasH. unfortunately we haven't gone into determinants or Laplace expansion at all.  How would you go about it with normal row reduction (as I attempted above)?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Why do there exist at most two numbers $c$ for which the three vectors are linearly dependent?

Comment: A bit confused, do you mean linearly independent?  If not, I don't think I'm getting the hint heh...